# How to run one default task on all celery workers when they are first initialized

Tags: parallel-processing, rabbitmq, celery, processing, monitoring

I have multiple celery workers running in separate docker containers. And my broker is rabbitmq My workers have concurrency value of 3. My goal is to run a system monitoring task on all the workers in parallel with other tasks submitted by users. The system monitoring task will need to be started right after the workers are first initialized and stay active as long as the workers are alive. So is there a way to start the system monitoring task automatically upon initialization on all the workers?